# How to handle alternative themes for visual impaired users

Tags: theme, accessibility

Has anyone got an thoughts on how to handle theming a WSS site for a single user who is visually impaired ... she uses high contrast settings for Word, etc.

But still leave the usual theme for everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the RNIB website. This is done on SharePoint - everything on the site has been tested to Surf Right standard. (WCAG 2.0 and above)
http://www.rnib.org.uk/Pages/Home.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One immediate option is the mobile SharePoint site (http://www.yoursharepointsite.com/m).

This allows anyone who is visually impaired to access the SharePoint site with minimal formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The org I'm currently working with does a some work that requires accessibility.  I've done some planning on for an updated design that would support CSS level reformatting to increase font sizes.  Think of a small-medium-large approach for both content and navigation.

Something like that may be a better option than alternative themes, but would require more work than the mobile version kkhipple mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Which reminds me, definitely have a look at HiSoftware Accessibility Kit for SharePoint.  Their SharePoint addon, provides additionality components that give you better control over the HTML generated by SharePoint; however, provided an alternate CSS is still the preferred method.